# Clarification on classes in python

Tags: python, class

I am new to Python (coming from MATLAB) and was beginning to learn that classes were a good way to modularize a program. I understand that they are like a "blueprint" that can streamline processes, but I think my understanding of that is faulty. I was reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) and came across this example:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
        self.r = realpart
        self.i = imagpart

x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)
x.r, x.i
```

with an output of

```
(3.0, -4.5)
```

And it stumped me. There are no functions known as `realpart` or `imagpart` to be passed and yet they are renamed as `r` and `i` and instantly work. They don't appear to be built in functions either.  How are `realpart` and `imagpart` doing anything?

NOTE: I apologize for the ambiguous title and tags, I'm not really sure what this would be called. I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Two great answers. for MATLAB users switching to python; Python's __init__ function inside classes pass information dramatically different than MATLAB's functions! Thanks DSM for an extended answer.

Comment: The `__init__` function "inside classes" is markedly different than MATLAB's functions because `__init__` it creates an instance of a class, in this case Complex.  In MATLAB, you define functions that you pass values to and return some kind of result usually.  Python can do that too, but what you're doing here is instantiating an object, so you're storing `realpart` and `imagpart` in the object.  Unlike python, MATLAB is not object-oriented, though it comes somewhat close with something called functional objects.

Comment: @nullpointer Thank you for the elaboration!

Comment: You're welcome.  Adjusting to Object Oriented Programming can be a bit jarring at first.  I know it's hard but you'll have to try to not compare too many things to how they were in MATLAB.  Good luck with your python endeavors!

Comment: Thanks again, I will try to keep my Python and MATLAB practices separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How are realpart and imagpart doing anything?

They're not doing anything: they're just the names given to the arguments to `__init__`.  We could call them `apple` and `pear` if we liked.  When you type

```
x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)
```

`__init__` is passed three arguments:

```
def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
```

the instance itself (traditionally called `self`), the first explicit argument passed (3.0), and the second explicit argument passed (-4.5).  It then stores these as instance variables in `self.r` and `self.i`.

Comment: So, by calling x=complex(3,-4.5), I am in essance giving `realpart` and `imagpart` a value? That can then be called by their shorter names `r` and `i`?

Comment: Are you reading the code?  You can't just ignore what it says in `__init__`.  The reason you can refer to them by `r` and `i` is because the code assigns those shorter names to them.  They don't magically get extra names.

Comment: wow, ok.. I was definitely thinking of this backwards. Thank you guys.

Comment: `realpart` and `imagpart` are given values, yeah, but only for the lifetime of the `__init__` method.  It's like `def f(a,b): return a+b`; `f(1,2)` does bind `a=1` and `b=2`, but only locally.  As BrenBarn says, it's the `self.r = realpart` which pushes the local `realpart` into the instance.

Answer (score 3):

`realpart` and `imagpart` are the arguments to the class initializer `__init__`.  When you call `Complex(3.0, -4.5)`, those arguments are passed to that function.  The function happens to set some attributes on the object to save the values of those arguments.  It does this with the lines

```
    self.r = realpart
    self.i = imagpart
```

These lines create attributes on the object.  When you create an object called `x`, it will have those attributes accessible as `x.r` and `x.i`.

I'm not sure why you're asking about "functions" called realpart and imagpart.  They are just ordinary variables.

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python.